# findFragmentByTag(fragment::class.simpleName) returns not null on build variant A and null on build variant B

Tags: android, gradle, android-fragments

```
if (this.childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment::class.simpleName) == null) {
     replaceFragment(containerId, fragment)
}
```

Why same fragment extension on the same screen for the same fragment works different for two different build variants?
I have two build types - A and B and I need to replace fragment if it is not added with code above. With build type A everything works okay, findFragmentByTag(fragment::class.simpleName) returns null and fragment replaces only when it needs, but with build type B the same code for the same fragment returns not null tag and fragment is not replaced.

This scenarios should work the same way

Comment: I think we need to see more code.

Comment: @KristyWelsh, added some description

Comment: We need to see more like how you've defined the fragment, etc.